# How to iterate and display each element from inner list - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, list, react-state, react-class-based-component

How to iterate and display each element from 'grandChildren' list -> for eg: ["AQ11", "AS12"]. Thank you.

responseData:

```
[{Key:"A",Value:["AQ11", "AS12"]}, {Key:"C",Value:["CN22", "CL33", "CV44"]}].
```

Have set KeyValuePair's key to 'children' and Value to 'grandChildren' state.

I am able to display children but not grandChildren as it returns list of values ["AQ11", "AS12"]. Tried below but could not succeed

```
render() {
        const child= Object.values(this.state.items);
        const grandChild= Object.values(this.state.items[i].grandChildren); // Not sure how to set -  how do I pass value of i. 

        return (
            <div>

                    {child.map((element, index) => {
                    <div key={index + element.children}>
                    return (                                                                                     
                         <Autocomplete                           
                            value={element.children}        // this displays children like "A" OR "C"                                                
                         />
                 
                            {grandChild.map((element1, index) => (                                                                       
                                <Autocomplete                                                      
                                value={element.grandChildren[element1]}  // NOT SURE HOW TO GET THIS TO WORK                                                
                                />                        
                            ))}
                    </div>
                    ))} 

                    );
           </div>
```

How do I iterate and display value of grandchildren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
render(){
  const child = Object.values(this.state.items);

  return (
    <div>
      {child.map((element, index) => {
        const grandChild = Object.values(this.state.items[index].grandChildren);

        return (
          <div key={index}>
            <Autocomplete
              value={element.children} // this displays children like "A" OR "C"
            />

            {grandChild.map((element1, index) => (
              <Autocomplete
                value={element1} 
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.